# how to generate OAuth nonce in numeric format for getting followers

Tags: twitter

I want to get oAuth nonce for https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json how can i get whether in php or iOS API

Answer (score 0):

If the question is "How can I generate an OAuth nonce in Objective-C?", then you should start from OAuth specification [section 3.3. Nonce and Timestamp](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.3).

For an Objective-C implementation, you can have a look at STTwitter's code for [generating nonces](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/blob/master/STTwitter/STTwitterOAuth.m#L159).

Basically, you can create a random string with the `CFUUIDCreateString()`. Taking the first 32 characters is enough.